# Magento 2.3 Admin Panel Edit Role Error

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3

I was trying to edit a user role (System -> Permission -> User Roles) on the magento 2.3.1 admin panel and I started to get this error:

```
[2019-06-17 08:34:01] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor) with the same ID "11" already exists. [] []
[2019-06-17 08:34:01] main.CRITICAL: The "adminhtml.user.editroles" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. [] []
```

I've tried to google the issue and I've seen similar errors relating to products, however, nothing to do with user roles.

The result of this error is that I see a mostly blank page with no ability to edit the assets that a role has access to.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please check your admin_users table by any chance, data with same Id exist. because this issue comes when we tried to modify entity with id which are duplicate.

Comment: @nishu I've checked this and confirmed that there are no duplicate user_id's